# Why x = y += 10 is invalid in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why *x = y += 10* is invalid while *x = y = y + 10* is valid.
Please help me figure it out.

```python
y = 11
x = y += 10
print(x)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In C and Java, `y += 10`  assigns a value to `y` but it is also an *expression*: it has a value that you can then assign to `x`. But in Python it is a *statement* like `break` which does not have a value you can assign to a variable. Python deliberately parted ways with the Algol/C/Java approach on this point. That is not unique: Wirth did the same with Pascal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x = y = 10` independently assigns 10 to `x` and `y`.  It specifically does not assign 10 to `y` and then `y` to `x`.  To prove it to yourself, try

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((1))
y = x[0] = 1
```

`y` now has the value `1`, while `x[0]` has the value `1.0`.

Under this interpretation, `x = y += 10` is rather ambiguous.

Comment: `x = y += 10` is not ambitious but forbidden by the language grammar. (But it is allowed and makes sense in C/Java.)

Comment: I interpreted the original poster's question to be "Why is it forbidden?"  I assumed he understood that it was forbidden, but didn't know why this seemingly arbitrary choice was made.

Answer (score 1):

`y += 10` is an [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/simple_stmts.html). An augmented assignment statement cannot be on the right-hand side of an assignment statement (such as `x=...`). Such are the rules of the Python language.

`x = y = y + 10` is a multiple assignment statement. It adds 10 to `y` and stores the result in `y` and `x`.